In what ways, if any, does the separation between SSDs affect a DAW?
This question brings out multiple opinions on the importance of having separate SSDs for a Digital Audio Workstation (DAW) and the operating system it runs on or the swap file.  It is a very old question, and I've also encountered a wide range of opinions on the importance of separating programs in general from the OS.
I am wondering which aspects of music production might be bottlenecked by having everything on the same, large SSD.  Would it merely slow down the process of exporting finished projects, or would it also reduce the maximum number of virtual instruments and plugins which could be active simultaneously/create latency/otherwise directly interfere with the producer's available options or base workflow?  On a modern laptop with at least 64 GB RAM (much more than in the linked question), would there even be any noticeable difference?

You probably won't notice significant performance difference between a single SSD versus "separate SSDs" unless you're experiencing write amplification. Seems like the use of multiple drives for performance is a carryover from use of HDDs, where seek time adds to the total R/W time. "This question brings out multiple opinions ..." - I don't agree with your assessment. IMO none of those three answers advocate the need for multiple or separate SSDs for performance reasons.

I still think the main answer there applies. Even the highest bitrates of raw uncompressed audio are not going to come close to saturating even an older SATA SSD, and NVMe drives are an order of magnitude faster. I suspect that any bottleneck is going to be in the actual decoding, processing and mixing and then encoding the output. I strongly suspect the bottleneck will be the CPU rather than SSD or even RAM. Modern NVMe SSDs can manage anywhere from 5GB/s and up and raw bitrates of audio will be a small fraction of that. To me this still feels like a duplicate of the other question.

As the answer on that question states, raw uncompressed 24-bit 96kHz audio will be about 576kB/s. A modern NVMe managing 5GB/s reading virtual instruments (with no caching in RAM) should be able to manage somewhere between 5,000 to 10,000 seconds worth of instrument work per second. The CPU would then have to interpolate and process all those samples together which could be a mathematically demanding process. If you factor in a large amount of RAM and caching of instruments then it boils down to whether instruments fit in RAM cache and even more of a CPU bottleneck.

As a musician myself, the answer is going to be very simple.
When you load in virtual instruments, they are loaded into memory. Unless you have instruments with many gigs of samples and you run out of memory, so the swapfile is used more, you will not have any impact from this at all.
I run my instruments from a network share which is far slower than an SSD, and all it does, is making my songs load a bit slower.
In some cases, VST instruments may choose to stream sample data directly from disk. These samples are usually installed directly to ProgramData, but the speed required of playing a sample from disk is so much slower than an SSD can bring, this is not a concern either.
If you render your song to wav, and that wav file is stored on the same drive as the swap, then maybe there will be a little bit of performance loss, but this really is only when you export the song, not when you play it back.
So while technically there could be a benefit from having 2 SSD's, one for swap, and one for exporting to, it is usually okay to wait those extra seconds and for that reason, you don't need to have multiple SSD's.
